# Database Design for Follow Users Feature with Large Scale

Tags: mysql, database-design

I’m trying to come up with a MySQL database schema to support a feature to store users following other users. I see two approaches:

1st approach) have a `users_following` table with two columns: `user_id` and `follower_id`. Problem I see with this approach is for popular users  with many followers, it would create many records in the table.

Alternative approach) have the `users_following` to store `user_id` and `follower_ids`, where the  `follower_ids` store the followers id in a list (comma separated).

Is there any problem with the alternative approach above?

UPDATE: 
For this feature, I do not need to query by the individual followers. The way this table will be used is the app will query for the user, then grab the followers and run some logic to it.

Comment: Warmly recommended reading: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/10676716)

Comment: @GMB Thanks, I will read it. There’s a part I should’ve included in the question: I do not need to query for the individual followers. Updated the question.

Comment: Suppose a user is deleted. You'd have to reevaluate **all** the lists. (similar for duplicates or updates)

Comment: The alternative idea is a terrible one

Comment: @Strawberry Could you elaborate on why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because it violates 3NF.

Comment: In addition to what Strawberry has said, there is also the fact that a comma separated list is likely to take MORE storage if your id values are normally 4 byte integers.

Comment: Approach 1 is the way to go.